# Space between navigation bar and drop-down bar

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to html, and when I tried to create a webpage, I encountered a problem. I managed to make a navigation bar with a drop down menu directly under the "Games" section, but if I scroll down and open the drop down menu, it no longer opens directly under the navigation bar. This is my HTML code.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="main-title">
        <header>
            <h1>Max Reviews</h1>
        </header>
    </div>                                                                              <!-- Title box-->
        <div id="nav">                                                                  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
            <nav>                                                                   
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>                          <!-- Link to about page -->
                    <li class="drop">
                        <a href="games.html" class="dropbtn"><p>Games</p></a>
                        <div class="drop-content">
                            <a href="rfg.html"><p>Red Faction: Guerrilla</p></a>                    <!-- Contains links to the respective pages -->
                            <a href="wots3.html"><p>Way of the Samurai 3</p></a>
                            <a href="singularity.html"><p>Singularity</p></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="external.html">External Store</a></li>                 <!-- Link to external site -->
                    <li><a href="video.html">Videos</a></li>                            <!-- Contains links to Youtube -->
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
  <div class="image">                                                               <!-- Banner-->
            <a href="singularity.html">
                <img src="modified singularity aging 1.jpg" alt="singularity">
                <h2><span>Recommended Game of the Month</span></h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="home-content"><p>Learn more about the site &#9755<a href="about.html">here</a>&#9754</p></div>
        <div id="footer">
        <p>&copy Copyright 2016-2017. All images here were taken and edited by me. All rights reserved. Games featured here might not be suitable for all audience.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

And this is the stylesheet.

```
article, body, div, footer, header, h1, h2, p {
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
    transition: background 600s ease-in-out;
}
body:hover {
    background-color: #4B0101;
}
/*main title*/
#main-title {
    background-color: #33B2E7;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    left: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: color 1s, transform 1s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
#main-title:hover {
    color: black;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
/* Nav */
#nav nav{
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1C86EE;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 16%;
}
li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.active {
    background-color: #6CCC0A;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
li a:hover, .drop:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #BFA811;
}
a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
li.drop {
    display: inline-block;
}
.drop-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #970707;
    min-width: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px #000000;
    z-index: 100;
}
.drop-content a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.drop-content a:hover {
    background-color: #02BBC4
}
.drop:hover .drop-content {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 155px;
    border: 1px solid black;;
}
/*banner*/
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.image h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    right: 350px;
}
.image h2 span {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: Arial, Calibri, Sans-serif;
    background: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
}
.image h2:hover span {
    background-color: #003316;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1013px;
    left: 700px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(41,120,104);
    color: rgb(240,144,22);
    font-family: Cambria, Times New Roman, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
/*content*/
#home-content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 90px;
    display: block;
    color: #8A0707
}
#home-content a {
    color: #09922A
}home-content a:visited {
    color: #000000
}
/*Footer*/
#footer {
    background: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#footer p {
    font-family: arial, calibri, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
#aboutme h2 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: Cambria, Calibri, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000000;
}
#aboutme article {
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial, cambria, serif;
    line-height: 200%;
    color: #777000;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    padding: 10px;
}
#gallery-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cambria, calibri, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 20px;  
}
#image-1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 25%;
    padding: 20px;
}
.img-desc-1 {
    padding: 20px;
    color: #047615;
}
#image-2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 25%;
    border: 2px solid #262020;
    padding: 20px;
}
#prompt-text {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-family: cambria, calibri, sans-serif;
}
.image-container img{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.image-container p{
    padding-left: 80px;
    font-family: Arial, cambria, sans-serif;
    color: #560404;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.image-container {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#image1 {
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 10%
}
#image2 {
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}
#image3 {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.gameimages {
    padding-bottom: 15%;
    text-align: center;
}
.gameimages p {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.gameimages h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cambria, times new roman, sans-serif
}
#side-nav {
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
    bottom: 1500px;
    right: 3%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #8C3406;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Please help me as I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 days. Also, this is my first time posting a question here, so forgive me if I indented my code wrongly, or if I inadvertently violated some of the rules of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Unable to reproduce your issue. I am able to open that drop down after scroll also. Which browser are you testing?

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code you post in questions to the bare minimum that is required to showcase your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I was using Google Chrome, and I'm sorry about all the codes. I'm still new to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that your drop-content has `position:fixed` on hover.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning):

> …an element that is absolutely positioned is taken out of the flow; thus, other elements are positioned as if it did not exist. The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its *nearest positioned ancestor*… Fixed positioning is similar to absolute positioning, with the exception that the element's containing block is the *viewport*.

[Working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yuz0qqm/) and here is what I've changed:

```
#nav ul {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

.drop:hover .drop-content {
  /*position: fixed;
  top: 155px;*/
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I tried it and it works. I used position: fixed for the .drop:hover and .drop-content class because I was following the example from W3Schools.

Answer (score 0):

Update CSS to

```
 article, body, div, footer, header, h1, h2, p {
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
    transition: background 600s ease-in-out;
}
body:hover {
    background-color: #4B0101;
}
/*main title*/
#main-title {
    background-color: #33B2E7;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    left: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: color 1s, transform 1s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
#main-title:hover {
    color: black;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
/* Nav */
#nav nav{
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #1C86EE;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 16%;
}
li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.active {
    background-color: #6CCC0A;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
li a:hover, .drop:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #BFA811;
}
a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
li.drop {
    display: inline-block;
}
.drop-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #970707;
    min-width: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px #000000;
    z-index: 100;
}
.drop-content a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.drop-content a:hover {
    background-color: #02BBC4
}
.drop:hover .drop-content {
    display: block;
}
/*banner*/
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.image h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    right: 350px;
}
.image h2 span {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: Arial, Calibri, Sans-serif;
    background: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
}
.image h2:hover span {
    background-color: #003316;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1013px;
    left: 700px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(41,120,104);
    color: rgb(240,144,22);
    font-family: Cambria, Times New Roman, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
/*content*/
#home-content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 90px;
    display: block;
    color: #8A0707
}
#home-content a {
    color: #09922A
}home-content a:visited {
    color: #000000
}
/*Footer*/
#footer {
    background: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#footer p {
    font-family: arial, calibri, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
#aboutme h2 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: Cambria, Calibri, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000000;
}
#aboutme article {
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial, cambria, serif;
    line-height: 200%;
    color: #777000;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    padding: 10px;
}
#gallery-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cambria, calibri, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 20px;  
}
#image-1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 25%;
    padding: 20px;
}
.img-desc-1 {
    padding: 20px;
    color: #047615;
}
#image-2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 25%;
    border: 2px solid #262020;
    padding: 20px;
}
#prompt-text {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-family: cambria, calibri, sans-serif;
}
.image-container img{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.image-container p{
    padding-left: 80px;
    font-family: Arial, cambria, sans-serif;
    color: #560404;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.image-container {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#image1 {
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 10%
}
#image2 {
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}
#image3 {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.gameimages {
    padding-bottom: 15%;
    text-align: center;
}
.gameimages p {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.gameimages h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cambria, times new roman, sans-serif
}
#side-nav {
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
    bottom: 1500px;
    right: 3%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #8C3406;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

2 changes done.

1. Removed `overflow:hidden` in `#nav ul`
2. Keot `display:block` only in `.drop:hover .drop-content`